How to resolve duplicate Video Items getting created in Sitecore Content Tree on Brightcove pull sync pipeline?
We have recently upgraded to Brightcove 10.1 connector. Right now we are using pull pipeline to fetch videos, player, playlist and label. But the duplicate video items are getting created even though we AllowDuplicateItemsOnSameLevel is set to false.

The issue is with indexing after rebuilding master index it has resolved the issue.

If issue is resolved you can close the question.
